# Django not getting images that are uploaded to sqlite

Tags: html, django, imagefield, display

Images are not coming into template.

### settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

### html

```
{% for question in question_list %}
<img src= "{{question.image}}">
```

### models.py

```
class NewQuestion(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200, unique = True, null =        False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Comment: if i type {{question.image}} on html i am getting images/frame.jpg

Comment: try `{{question.image.url}}`

Answer (score 0):

To render a photo from an ImageField in Django's templating language, the following syntax is required:

```
{{ image.url }}
```

In your case:

```
{% for question in question_list %}
    <img src= "{{ question.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for question in question_list %}
   <img src= "{{question.image.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Reference to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url):

> A read-only property to access the file’s relative URL by calling the url() method of the underlying Storage class.

#### Update:

Adding this to your **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I also kept {%endfor%} but I am not getting images.

Comment: I want to know the exact location of images where to store, currently my images are automatically stored in media/images

Comment: the images are directly stored in 'media/images' as you have specified [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-root) as `media` and [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) as `images`

Comment: and its not `{{questions.image.url}}` but `{{question.image.url}}`

Comment: I wrote {{question.image.url}} only

Comment: Ok, may be its a typo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020014/django-not-getting-images-that-are-uploaded-to-sqlite/34020200?noredirect=1#comment55797403_34020200) :). Did it work then?

Comment: when i am keeping {{question.image.url}} it is printing images/frame.jpg on page if i am typing that in img tag as <img src = "{% static images.frame.jpg %}", I am getting image, but I want the image dynamically.

Comment: Have you added the URL pattern for serving the media files? [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))                         MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media'). I added these in settings.py

Comment: @ Ankit Popli - Sir, thank you very much, I added URL pattern and got it.

Comment: Is the procedure same to upload audio fields

Comment: My pleasure, Yes the procedure is same except you'll need to use `FileField` instead of `ImageField`.